# PopUp for TableHeader td Column

Tags: javascript, css, popup, mouseover, tableheader

I have a table in cold fusion with a thead tag and multiple td tags. I want to have a div popup when a user hovers over the td tag with id="trigger". I've tried a bunch of different variations using css and jquery, but for some reason they are not working.

1: Is there a way I can do it using css alone?

2: Any suggestions on how to do it using jquery?

I've tried this on jfiddle and stuff that works on there is not working in my ColdFusion code.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice for you, to show your fiddle to us to help you :)

Comment: Just FYI: as this is a client-side issue, it's got nothing to do with ColdFusion / CFML. I've adjusted the title and removed the ColdFusion tag (and gonna retag it with JavaScript so as to get the right audience looking at it)